# Copying row by row

Tags: vba, excel

I need help copying values from one worksheet to another. Here is the code I'm using, but it won't work.

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook

    'open the source workbook and select the source sheet
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open( _
        Filename:="C:\Users\B48184\Desktop\Losses_Breakdown_by_OEE.xls")

    'Set the destition workbook variable
    Set wbDestination = Workbooks("TryVB.xlsm")

    wbSource.Sheets("Report").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(14, 8)).Copy
    wbDestination.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(14, 8)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The unqualified `Cell(...` 's refer to the active sheet, which may be different to the specified sheet, causing an error.   Change to

```
With wbSource.Sheets("Report")
    .Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(14, 8)).Copy
End With
With wbDestination.Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(14, 8)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Note the `.`'s.

Answer (score -1):

How about if you do this:

```
wbSource.Sheets("Report").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(14, 8)).Copy
wbDestination.Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(14, 8)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

This should work.